# How can i remove or replace question mark from url using wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm showing child categories data in custom page using wordpress. Problem is that i'm fetching those child categories from parent category slug.

`www.example.com/custom/?cp=category-slug`

I want to remove `?cp=`  and make it like thiss `www.example.com/custom/category-slug`.

Is there any way to rewrite this specific custom page url, i will appreciate if someone help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins who can make you achieve this goal, for instance https://wordpress.org/plugins/pretty-url/ or https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this, you can create a custom category template to list all of its sub-category data. Refer this https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates Its url would be www.example.com/custom-post-type-slug/category-slug Also it won't affect other category pages.

Step-1: Create a category template:

In your themes folder, create a .php file as save as category-slug.php

Step-2: Add a loop to list all its subcategory data

Just copy and paste the below code:

```
   <?php
        $cat_name=get_category($cat);
        $cat_id=$cat_name->cat_ID;
        $categories = get_categories("child_of=".$cat_id);

        foreach ($categories as $cat) { ?>

            <div class="subcategory">
                <?php query_posts("cat=$cat->cat_ID&showposts=-1&order=ASC&orderby=name"); ?>
                        <h4 ><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h4>
                        <hr>
                        <ul>
                        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();

                            ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                </li>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
             </div>
        <?php }?>
```

Change that loop according to your needs.